# How/where are template-functions allocated?

Tags: c++, creation, function-template

Is the following use of the template-function `fCompare()` correct?

//header

```
template<typename _T > class SomeClass
{
    typedef int (*COMPAREFUNC)(_T*,_T*);
    COMPAREFUNC Compare;
public:
    void SetCompareFunction(COMPAREFUNC pfC) { Compare=pfC; }
    ...
};

template<typename _T > int fCompare(_T *pO, _T *pN)
{
    if (pN==NULL) throw (const char*)"Null not allowed";
    if (pO!=NULL) return (*pO > *pN)?1:(*pO < *pN)?(-1):0;
    return 0;
}
```

//code

```
    SomeClass<int> aC;

    aC.SetCompareFunction(fCompare<int>); //                <******* here
    ...
```

My worry is where the instance function is created from the template: it *looks* like the stack, but in other code I used to test it, I tried to hammer the stack, and the `Compare()` just kept on going. Can I safely use the template like this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "hammer the stack?"  C++ templates typically are implemented by expanding out into normal functions, so they should behave as such.  Without knowing what you did to try to destroy the program, I'm not sure how much I can help.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'm an ex-C-programmer, so anything that's passed as function-parameters goes on the stack .. not always so in C++, which makes me happy because this template-stuff really make coding a lot simpler.

Comment: @slashmais that entirely depends on the implementation.

Comment: @daknok_t: yeah - I had a look at Boost & I'm nowhere near fully understanding all the tricks they 'commit' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fCompare<int>` is created at compile time, as part of the code segment. You can think of it as a sort of constant, static data, just like a `const int` at file scope would be. Each time you invoke `SetCompareFunction`, therefore, it receives a pointer to the *same function*. Thus, no matter how many times you invoke it, it won't use up any extra memory, and you won't run out of stack or heap space just from doing so.

The corollary to this is that template function arguments must always be something that can be computed at compile time. It's illegal to pass in a variable (except for a template variable) as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, yes. Expanded template functions are the same as normal functions; in your example, fCompare<int> would be the same as an independent function called fCompare_int, with int substituted for the template parameter. Since you're effectively just taking the address in the function call, all is good.